# Sparklyr/sparc_read_csv: Ignore \r\n while reading data

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have received a large CSV file (50 million entries) with the following format:

url,httpsStatusCode,newURL,Payload

where the last variable includes the complete HTML code. vroom() is able to read these four columns without a problem but due to the size of the data frame, I want to process it in Spark(lyr).

I have tried to use sparc_read_csv from the Sparklyr package but with no success as each \r\n or \n results in a new row. I remember there was something like a multiline parameter in Spark but it doesn't seem to be available in Sparklyr :(

Here is some sample data in a file e.g. test.csv:

```
http://domain/,301 Moved Permanently,https://domain/,"<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
"
```

And here is the code that I have been using:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", 
                    version = "3.1")
data <- spark_read_csv(sc, "data", "test.csv", header = FALSE)
```

I cannot copy the base data frame to Spark with sdf_copy_to as some HTML code will include ","s that will result in (too many) additional columns. I assume that the best solution would be to have a CSV file without newlines and returns but that's not an option right now.

Comment: We need more than just one entry of the example csv to see the delimiter you used. Spark is for distributed computing on multiple servers, it does not make much sense using it locally. The number of entries is not meaningful to decide which tool to use for loading.

Comment: @danlooo I disagree. Distributing the work to several cores (I have 10 in my MBP with 64GB of RAM) has accelerated my work tremendously, especially when I look at larger files. Sure, using multiple machines would be even better. The delimiter is a "," as you can see in the example.

Comment: You do not need the data locality paradigm, because your workflow seems to be not IO but CPU bounded (Parsing is slower than just reading the file), thus you do not need spark here

Comment: @danlooo With all due respect, I don't get your point. The data is too big to handle in base R while I can import it there (how useful that is, that's another question because there is no lazy loading). I cannot import it into Spark where I could process it. I am looking for a way to import and parse it with the before mentioned issues.